# Custom Tagging messages in IMAP through python

Tags: python, imap

Is there a way to tag messages in IMAP folder with Python to custome tag? like Toms mail, john's weeding crap etc etc?

Comment: [IMAP RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-2.3.2) specifies that clients may be able to set their own flags, but leaves it up to the servers whether or not they support arbitrary flags.

Comment: Take a look at http://imapclient.freshfoo.com/. I don't know if it does what you need as I'm not really sure what you want to do. It _might_ be of some use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Cyrus IMAP server](http://cyrusimap.web.cmu.edu/) supports user-defined message flags (aka tags, labels, keywords), and you can use the [Alpine mail client](http://www.washington.edu/alpine/) for experimentation with labels.  In Alpine choose `(S)etup` -> `(C)onfig`, scroll down to the `keywords` section and enter your list of desired flag names.

To set the message flags from Python you can use the standard imaplib module.  Below is an example of setting flags on a message:

```
import imaplib
im = imaplib.IMAP4(hostname)
im.login(user, password)
im.select('INBOX')

# you can use im.search() to obtain message ids
msg_ids = '1, 4, 7'
labels = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

# add the flags to the message
im.store(msg_ids, '+FLAGS', '(%s)' % ' '.join(labels))

# fetch and print to verify the flags
print im.fetch(ids, '(FLAGS)')

im.close()
im.logout()
```

One thing to keep in mind is that the flags sent to the server do not contain spaces.  If you send `+FLAGS (foo bar)` to the server, this will set two flags `foo` and `bar`.  Clients like Alpine will let you enter flags with spaces in them, but will only send the last non-space part to the server -- it treats this like a unique identifier.  If you specify the flag `abc 123` it will set the `123` on the message and display `abc` in the message view.

Answer (score 1):

You may use imap_tools package:
https://pypi.org/project/imap-tools/

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, Q
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'pwd', initial_folder='INBOX') as mailbox:
    # FLAG unseen messages in current folder as Answered and Flagged, *in bulk.
    flags = (imap_tools.StandardMessageFlags.ANSWERED, imap_tools.StandardMessageFlags.FLAGGED)
    mailbox.flag(mailbox.fetch('(UNSEEN)'), flags, True)
```

How to use keyword criteria for custom flags:

https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools/blob/master/examples/keyword_criteria_and_custom_flags.py

Comment: I think you may have imported `Q` by mistake.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't letting me withdraw my upvote, but this answer doesn't say anything about _custom_ tags; it only shows how to use the `StandardMessageFlags`.

Comment: @MichaelScheper, fixed